# WriteLog( ... ) function in C++

Tags: c++, logging, iostream

I'm trying to find a decent way to do logging from C++. My current solution is this:

```
ostream & GetLog() { if( output == NULL ) throw error; return *output; }
```

Where output is defined somewhere and can be a file or whatever. This is fine, but it doesn't let me do anything other than throw an error if output is not allocated. Also, my program is multithreaded, and I need to obtain a lock in order to correctly check if output is not NULL and then write to it if it is not. Ideally, any code that uses GetLog() should obtain that lock:

```
{
    LockLog lock;
    if( HasLog() )
        GetLog() << "My dog ate " << n << " cookies!" << endl;
}
```

This seems like too much verbiage to me. I'd like to do something like just

```
GetLog() << "My dog ate " << n << " cookies!" << endl;
```

and have it work without an error when the log's not allocated (and with lock), or a function like

```
WriteLog( "My dog ate " << n << " cookies!" << endl );
```

I know with C printf syntax this can be done with variable argument function. Is there a way to do this with C++ syntax and without a macro that would force me to expose the GetLog, HasLog, and LockLog functions anyway?

Comment: If you like `printf`, what keeps you from using it? It's inside `<cstdio>`.

Comment: @zneak, obviously my problem is not where to find printf. I'm just used to the iostream syntax, and all my code is written using it, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html/), which is a

> decent way to do logging from C++

that you are unlikely to be able to match in a timely way.  Even if this seems like overkill now you may find that your diagnostic needs grow as your system does, making the logging component a time sink that was not envisaged at the start.

I find I both save time, and learn good design from better developers, when I use well-designed, robust frameworks like this (cf. Boost, STL).

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
class Log {
    class buffer {
        buffer(...);
        ~buffer() {
            Lock lock(mutex);
            // write in destrcutor
        }
        string data;
        Mutex &mutex;
    };
    Mutex mutex;
...
};

template<class T>
Log::buffer operator<<(Log& l, T t) {
    return t;
}

template<class T>
Log::buffer& operator<<(Log::buffer& b, T t) {
    return b += t;
}

Log log;

log << "blah" << 6;
```

Comment: That might work poorly in a MT environment, since you only lock for each '<<' operator invocation...

Comment: @Nick fair enough, give me sec

Comment: Shouldn't lock be a singleton/monostate kind of a class?

Comment: @Chu fair enough, give me sec

Answer (score 1):

For the formatting you might try boost::format

http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/format/index.html

Answer (score 0):

From experience, I would write a function which takes a string (or list of strings), and locks/logs inside the function. Leave the formatting outside the actual logging function, so you ensure that everything gets logged in the same block for a single logical log message.

You could do something like I did to handle the formatting, which is: create a string-derived class with a printf-style constructor, and use it inline.

So, for example:

```
class PFString : public string
{
public:
    PFString( const char* pcszFormat, ... )
    { ... }
};

Log( PFString( "something with number %d", 42 ) );
```

Of course, you're free to format the string other ways too (eg: C++ operator style syntax, resource string formatting, etc.).